# Adding a prefix to the location in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, winginx

I want to add a location with a prefix so that my app works similar to the one without slash,

eg:

```
server_name mydomain.com
location /{
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

with the above config, the app is working, but I have multiple apps to be used with the same domain with a prefix like mydomain.com/app1 ; mydomain.com/app2

Now for the above I have a config something like below,

```
server_name mydomain.com
location /app1/{
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

but this one is not loading all my static file like css/js etc and app is not working, can you please help me.